# Let $G$ be a connected graph. If $G$ has no cut vertices, then G has no bridges.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Prove, disprove, or give a counterexample: Let $G$ be a connected graph. If $G$ has no cut vertices, then $G$ has no bridges.

Comment: I'd go about it by trying to find a counterexample. If I luck out and find a counterexample, I'm done. If I try hard and can't get a counterexample, maybe I've got some insight into what is blocking the counterexample, and maybe I can turn that into a proof. So I'd start by drawing a bridge and asking myself, how can I keep the endpoints of the bridge from being cut vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that if $G$ has a bridge, then $G$ has a cut vertex. Specifically, prove the an endpoint of a bridge is a cut vertex. This statement is logically equivalent to the original problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).

Edit: You cannot actually prove the above statement for 2 vertices because there is a rather simple counter example as explained in the comments. But for larger graphs you can ensure that one of the vertices are a cut vertex as long as it is part of a connected component of size 3 or more.

Comment: What about the graph consisting of two vertices joined by an edge? Does that have a bridge? Does it have a cut vertex?

Comment: It does not. That is a counter example.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. It doesn't say anything about having at least 3 vertices so the trivial case n=2 must be the counterexample.

Comment: @CharlesNosbig yeah, I would say that is the correct answer. Although if this is homework, it might be cool to mention that it does work for larger graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least $3$ vertices, this is true.

With $2$ vertices, just think of the only connected graph possible.

See @Danikar's good answer.